# How do I join two columns in python, whilst one column has a url in every row, and other column has list of last part of the url

Tags: python

I have two columns:

One looks like:

```
"Link": "https://url.com/item?variant=",
"Link": "https://url2.com/item?variant=",
"Link": "https://url3.com/item?variant=",
```

2nd looks like:

```
"link extension": ["1","2"],
"link extension": ["1","2"],
"link extension": ["1","1","3"],
```

What I'm trying to do is to combine them together so that my Link column looks like this:

```
"Link": "https://url.com/item?variant=1"
"Link": "https://url.com/item?variant=2"
"Link": "https://url2.com/item?variant=1"
"Link": "https://url2.com/item?variant=2"
"Link": "https://url3.com/item?variant=1"
"Link": "https://url3.com/item?variant=2"
"Link": "https://url3.com/item?variant=3"
```

However, I'm a beginner of Python - and even basic level at Pandas. I tried to find the answer, and I came across map/append options but none of them seem to work throwing different TypeError

Any help or advice on what/where to read would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my basic code:

```
def parse(self, response):

    items = response.xpath("//*[@id='bc-sf-filter-products']/div")
    for item in items:
        link = item.xpath(".//div[@class='figcaption product--card--text under text-center']/a/@href").get()
        yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    Title = response.xpath(".//div[@class='hide-on-mobile']/div[@class='productTitle']/text()").get()
    Item_Link = response.url
    n_item_link = f"{Item_Link}?variant="

    idre = r'("id":\d*)' #defining regex
    id = response.xpath("//script[@id='ProductJson-product']/text()").re(idre) #applying regex
    id1 = [item.replace('"id":', '') for item in id] #cleaning list of url-ids
    id2 = id1[1:] #dropping first item

    test = n_item_link.append(id2) # doesn't work
    test2 = n_item_link.str.cat(id2) # doesn't work either

    yield{
        'test':test,
        'test2':test2
    }
```

Comment: Please post your code, point out where its not working so we can help fixing it.

Comment: I have added - please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# recreating the DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "link": ["https://url.com/item?variant=",
             "https://url2.com/item?variant=",
             "https://url3.com/item?variant="],
    "variants" : [["1","2"],
                  ["1","2"],
                  ["1","1","3"]]
                   }
                  )

#creating a new column containg the lenght of each list
df["len_list"] = [len(x) for x in df["variants"].to_list()]
# creating a list of all values in df.variants and converting values to string 
flat_list_variants = [str(item) for sublist in  df["variants"].to_list() for item in sublist]

# creating a new DataFrame which contains each index replicated by the lenght of df["len_list"]
df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.len_list)]
# assign the list to a new column
df_new["flat_variants"] = flat_list_variants
#compose the result by sum strings
df_new["results"] = df_new["link"] + df_new["flat_variants"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although my knowledge using pandas within python is limited, and I resolved the issue by using pure python for my task. I do appreciate your help and hope to use it in my future projects. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly your input looks like but assuming you have a list (or a different iterable) for your links and your extensions this will work:

```py
def join_url(links, ext_lists):
    urls = []
    for link, extension_list in zip(links, ext_lists):
        for extension in extension_list:
            urls.append(link + extension)
    return urls
```

Sample input:

```py
websites = ['web1&hello=', 'web2--', 'web3=']
extensions = [['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['3', '1']]
url_list = join_url(websites, extensions)
print(url_list)
```

Output:

```py
['web1&hello=1', 'web1&hello=2', 'web2--1', 'web2--2', 'web2--3', 'web3=3', 'web3=1']
```

Comment: Thank you, my Link is not a list, I extract it as a single value. However, extensions are extracted as list. I have updated my question with the code if that helps. What I want is to add extension to same url and create new row items rather than another list.

Comment: When I use this, I'm getting an error: TypeError: join_url() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Please tell what kind of input you have (you are talking about columns but there isn't any built-in type column; if you use a library-specific type please mention it). and when you want to call the function and with which arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your help  @kesslwovv - I'm using Python/Scrapy framework. However, I have managed to resolve the issue by using a loop before yielding results. Your suggestion did give me some ideas. So thank you :)